# AngularJS resolve not passing argument to the controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I want to set the resolve property on the route. When the route is `/home`, `test` should be set — as the following demonstrates:

```js
.when('/home', {
          controller: 'home',
          templateUrl: "application/views/Angular_spa/angular_templates/homepage.html",
          resolve: {
              test: function () {
                  return 'test variable';
              }
          }
      })
```

The `home` controller code is as follows:

```js
application.controller('home', function ($scope, $routeParams, $http, contentService, newsService, announceService, test) {

    newsService.getAllNews(function (data) {
        $scope.news = data; //U scopeu imamo novosti
    });
    announceService.getAllAnnouncments(function (data) {
        $scope.announcments = data;
    });

    $scope.siteURL = URLServer;
})
```

And I get the following error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.15/$injector/unpr?p0=testProvider%20%3C-%20test
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:6:450
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:34:510
    at Object.c [as get] (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:33:83)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:35:59
    at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:33:83)
    at d (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:33:300)
    at Object.instantiate (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:33:464)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:65:486
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.15/angular.min.js:52:156 <div ng-view="" class="centersection ng-scope">
```

Why can't I pass `test` from the resolve to the `home` controller and assign it later to `$scope.something` property, what I'm doing wrong?

Below is the module definition:

```js
var application = angular.module('content', ['ngRoute', 'ngSanitize'])

    .config(function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider
        .when('/home/content/:contentId', {
            controller: 'content',
            templateUrl: "application/views/Angular_spa/angular_templates/content.html"
        })
        .when('/home', {
            redirectTo: '/'
        })
        .when('/', {
            controller: 'home',
            templateUrl: "application/views/Angular_spa/angular_templates/homepage.html"
            resolve: {
                test: function () {
                    return 'test variable';
                }
            }
        })
        .when('/about-us', {
            controller: 'aboutus',
            templateUrl: "application/views/Angular_spa/angular_templates/content.html"
        })
        .when('/contact-us', {
            controller: 'contactus',
            templateUrl: "application/views/Angular_spa/angular_templates/content.html"
        })
        .when('/branch/:branchId', {
            controller: 'branch',
            templateUrl: "application/views/Angular_spa/angular_templates/branch.html"
        })
        .when('/home/downloads', {
            controller: 'downloads',
            templateUrl: "application/views/Angular_spa/angular_templates/download.html"
        })
        .when('/home/feedback', {
            controller: 'feedback',
            templateUrl: "application/views/Angular_spa/angular_templates/feedback.html"
        })
});
```

Comment: It should work. Show where you define the module. Is the configuration where you declare the `$routeProvider` in the same module (or in dependencies) as the controller?

Comment: Yes, the config and controller belongs to the same module.

Comment: I've updated my question, so now it is more clear what I want to do. I'm still getting the same error. Please help!

Comment: Have you tried using the latest stable version (Angular JS 1.2.15)?

Comment: how do you know the injector errs on `test`? what's the rest of the stack trace?

Comment: I assume the code you use to test has a comma after the second templateUrl

Comment: Yes, I've checked and there is comma after my template.

Comment: @EliranMalka I've updated the question, and added the full stack trace.

Comment: When I don't pass test variable to the controller, everything is working fine. When I pass test variable to the controller the I get the error above. Interesting is when I pass the test into the controller and alert(test) I get the value. Really don't know what is happening here?

Comment: it must be somewhere else. here's a [simplified version of your app](http://plnkr.co/edit/cre82t3RoihLpKqyclSg?p=preview), it works without particular problems.